# How does the bootstrap navbar remove the menu button and add it?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In a nav bar like this:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

When the window gets small enough the menu items disappear and the 3 lined button appears. I was wondering what changes are occurring when this occurs. I especially want to know what classes are added to what. My code is the following and acts like the link above. I have used inspect element but I don't see any changes occurring. Thanks!

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button id="menuButton" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <h4>Title</h4>
          </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#" >B</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#"  >C</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no class-toggling behind this particular change; while you're inspecting the element, watch the CSS that's being applied. The different forms of the navbar display are based on media queries. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
      display:none
  }
}
```

is the css that makes the menu icon button disappear at larger screen sizes.

Comment: is the width referring to the window width or document width? Thanks!